# Simple javascript lead delivery in to an Exact Target list?

Tags: javascript, marketing-cloud, api

I have a client who I've given both the web collect and the API methods of delivery as options to implement on their website lead forms so we can automate their emails.  They have an issue with the lead forms - saying that they are pre-built and they drop them on to their landing pages - they aren't easily able to change the code in them.  The do have a CRM system that the leads are getting delivered to via a simple piece of Javascript code that they've place on the page.  They tell me this snippet of code references the actual code it requires somewhere else, and translates the form field information this way and delivers it to the CRM correctly.  Is this a thing??  If so, is there a similar method of delivery in to a list in Exact Target??

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't directly exist in ExactTarget, no.  All interactions are expected to happen on the server-side. The reason for this is security - you wouldn't want just anyone or anything being able to have access to your account.

If you want to perform this function on the client side, you would want to build the integration as a REST route, and call directly from your front end page.

```
//backend pseudo-code
post "addSubscriber" (field inputs)
  //code to add new subscriber here

//frontend pseudo-code
$.ajax({
  url: "http://myserver.com/addSubscriber", 
  data: form data,
  type: post
})
```